# Can't get rid of some characters when pushing string to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, tags

I'm creating some kind of custom tags that I'll use later to filter some datas. However, when I add the tags inside an array, I get the following:

"[\"witcher 3\", \"badass\", \"epic\"]"

```
 @tags = []
        params[:tags].split(', ').map do |tag|
          @tags.push(tag.strip)
        end

# About 5 lines under

FileDetail.create!(path: path, creation_date: date, tags: @tags)
```

Why do these `\` show up, and why don't `.strip` work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting an array of strings in `@tag`, and `\"` represents an [escaped character](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings), in this case `"` which is used by ruby to represent `String` objects.

Consider the following code (an try it on IRB):

```
foo = ["bar", "baz"]
#=> ["bar", "baz"]

foo.inspect
#=> "[\"bar\", \"baz\"]"

foo.each { |f| puts "tag: #{f}" }
# tag: bar
# tag: baz
```

As you can see, there is really no `\` character to strip from the string, its just how ruby outputs a `String` representation. So your code doesn't need `.strip` method:

```
 @tags = []
 params[:tags].split(', ').map do |tag|
   @tags.push(tag)
 end
```

---

Not related to your question, but still relevant: `split` method will return an array, so there is no need to create one before and then push items to it; just assign the returned array to `@tags`.

For example:

```
params[:tags] = "witcher 3, badass, epic"
#=> "witcher 3, badass, epic"

@tags = params[:tags].split(', ')
#=> ["witcher 3", "badass", "epic"]
```

If you want, you can still use `map` and `strip` to remove leading and trailing spaces:

```
params[:tags] = "witcher 3,     badass    , epic    "
#=> "witcher 3,     badass    , epic    "

params[:tags].split(",").map(&:strip)
#=> ["witcher 3", "badass", "epic"]
```

Comment: This is the first time ever that what I though was an issue on Stack overflowwasn't one. Thank you for the highlight!

Comment: @Jaeger Glad to help! Also check the updated answer for an additional tip for your code.

Comment: Thank you, I already knew these tricks, but I'll use them soon anyway :)